# ROS -- kobuki_interbotix_kinect.urdf.xacro not found

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot2, turtlebot-gazebo

I'm setting up my system a so that I can run turtlebot2i on simulation. The robot is present at the lab in my university.

I have installed ubuntu xenial, ros-kinetic because apparently it has all the [features](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/) and gazebo7.

When I run the command -

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

I get the error -

> No such file or directory:
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_interbotix_kinect.urdf.xacro
> None None while processing
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
> Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter
> [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py
> '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_interbotix_kinect.urdf.xacro']
> returned with code [2].  Param xml is

And when I check the directory it is indeed not there -

> ubuntuxenial@ubuntuxenial:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_description/robots$
> ls create_circles_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro
> kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro create_circles_kinect.urdf.xacro
> kobuki_hexagons_r200.urdf.xacro kobuki_hexagons_astra.urdf.xacro
> roomba_circles_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro
> kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro_offset.urdf.xacro
> roomba_circles_kinect.urdf.xacro
> kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro

What should I do to fix this? Make changes to the launch file? And where do I get the kobuki_interbotix_kinect.urdf.xacro file because it's not there on GitHub